# MONO GTK#: Event when a window is focused on

Tags: events, combobox, mono, window, gtk#

I am trying to get a ComboBox to update in Window 1, when I close Window2.

Is there an easy way in how I can fire an event when Window 1 gets focused on again, so the combo updates??

Since the combo is in Window1, I cannot use the event when Window2 closes to update the Combo unless I make it public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Gtk's FocusIn event to get notified when a window becomes focused.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the chosen answer, I had to google again to find out how to use the FocusIn event, so here is some additional information for noobs like me:
In the application initialization add:

```
this.FocusInEvent += OnWindowFocus;
```

to hook into the event and call a function. Then declare the function:

```
protected void OnWindowFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Do stuff when the MainWindow gets focus here
}
```